# How to avoid FPS droping when templatematching with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I have dedicated myself to making a bot that detects 4 symbols in a game, it only appears one symbol at a time, in general I have managed to have 20 FPS on average but when the match is made, the FPS drops to 1-3 and the and delays the excecution some miliseconds and this makes the boss miss the symbols.
I know that it can use GPU in CPU because opencv uses CPU by default but I am not sure how to do this implementation.

What else could I do so that there is not so much FPS drop in templatematching?

I have the code divided into 3 scripts, main.py, WindowsCapture.py, Vision.py.

In the WindowCapture I am charged with reading the screen, passing it to grayscale, edge and returning it to image.

The Vision is in charge of matching the 4 possibilities and capturing windowsCapture.

I attach the github link so you can see my code https://github.com/humbertoscorza/BotTest

Since they will need an account and have an NFT (it is an nft game) I pass them captures that if they put them in full screen on a monitor with 1920, 1080 resolution it should detect the symbols.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/441264410997030914/884975954789802004/unknown.png https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/441264410997030914/884975745393389588/unknown.png https://cdn.dischcordapp.com/attachments/441264410997030914/884975665043112016/unknown.png https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/441264410997030914/884975369344659476/unknown.png

Comment: Please, update the question with the relevant code, preferably a [mre].

Comment: you can add gpu support but thats not your problem, your problem is that you have a `sleep(0.5)` under `pressKey` method, when the symbol detected the method executed and the capture of next frame is delayed by 0.5 second

Comment: @LichKing is there a way to make it kinda async so it can always work without a delay? or what should i do

Comment: first you can improve your code by running the detection method on every second frame, this will boost the frame rate,
about the delay that you have in keypress method, you could open worker thread to execute keypress commands

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.